# What is the Commons Lang and how do I use it? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons-lang

I was trying to find a way to do some string manipulation and ran across the Commons Lang in a response to another question posted here on stackoverflow.  From what I can tell it's a collection of libraries, do I have to download and somehow import this to eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commons Lang as you put it is just a general purpose common library that provides a number of useful features.

To use it you need to download the JAR and add it to the Java Build path in Eclipse.  See:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962

Answer (score 1):

[Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) is a library from Apache that you can download and include in your project like any other 3rd party jar.